# JavaScript/jQuery Chaining Tag Replacement Calls

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble having the 2nd call to .replaceWith overwrite the old content written with .replaceWith. How do you handle an issue like below :

```
if (data==-3){  
       $('message').replaceWith('ffgd');                                        
} else if (data==-4){
       $('message').replaceWith('dfdsfdsfds');
```

On the first call when data is -3, I see ffgd. Then when a 2nd call occurs and data=-4, I know that the else if block is run because of console.log messages but it doesnt overwrite the ffgd.

Comment: Is `message` an element??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you use `replaceWith` the original element is gone... there is no `message` tag to replace the second time.

Perhaps you want to replace it's contents which can be done using `text()` or `html()` methods

See API docs:  http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/